# joining two tables issue 8

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with this join...

Here are my 2 tables, adds and adds_filters

```
adds_filters structure:

addfilterid
addid
filterid

  data the table look like this:
  addfilterid     addid     filterid    
  1               31        65
  2               31        158
  3               32        109
  4               32        145 



adds structure

addid
addtitle
addtext



 data the table look like this:
 addid    addtitle     addtext
 31       test         test
 32       test2        test2
```

One add can have many filters. I want to get all filters that are in the adds_filters and display the results from table adds.
I have the following query...

```
SELECT * , af.filterid, af.addid
FROM `adds` AS a
INNER JOIN `adds_filters` AS af ON a.addid = af.addid
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

In the table adds, i have 9 records. The above query returns 11 results. I would like to get 9 records and if one add have more then one filter, to be displayed in the same row...hos can i do that?

Regards, John

Comment: Which "one" should be shown on that same row?

Comment: Use `group by` and `group_concat`

Comment: i would like to get add with id 31 for example to show me that has filters 65 and 158 for example...

Comment: @user2417624 without seeing your data I'm afraid your explanation does not make sense.

Comment: i just edit the post...can you please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
SELECT a.* , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT af.filterid)
FROM `adds` AS a
JOIN `adds_filters` AS af ON a.addid = af.addid
GROUP BY a.addid
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: this query produces wrong number of records, and display [BLOB - 11 B] in the field:GROUP_CONCAT(af.filterid, '-',af.addid)

Comment: hi...still same result

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your query 11 records appears tobe the correct result because one add has more then one filter.
So if every add has at least one filter and some of them two or more the result would be more then 9 rows.

This is my explanation but maybe you would like to accomplish something else?

My question why do you expect 9 rows?

Comment: I didn't expect, i would like to get 9 records, with the filters included in that row somehow if that is possible.

Comment: with the answer i posted you get 1 row for every add and in the column headers the filtername and for every occurence of the filter there is a 1

Answer (score 0):

You might try this.

maybe it gets close to your wishes.

```
TRANSFORM Count(adds_filters.filterId) AS sumOffilterId
SELECT adds.addid, adds.addtitle, adds.addtext
FROM adds INNER JOIN adds_filters ON adds.addid = adds_filters.addid
GROUP BY adds.addid, adds.addtitle, adds.addtext
PIVOT adds_filters.filterId;
```

addid   addtitle    addtext 65  109 145 158

31  test    test    1           1

32  test2   test2       1   1

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRANSFORM Count(adds_filters.filterId) AS sumOffilterId SELECT adds.addid, adds' at line 1 is what i get

Comment: Hmm, mysql doesn't support Pivot,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117521/mysql-pivot-table-head-scratcher. this link refers to an article how to implement a pivot table in MySql